# How to change numbers into formatted strings

Tags: c#, .net

How do I format numbers into strings in C#?

For instance, how do I take a number like 34549321 and display it as 34,549k?

Comment: I've made a very significant edit to your post in an attempt to make it more clear. tell me if I'm wrong, and i'll go revert it back

Comment: @Dork can you provide a xaml sample / code behind / view model showing where the data is coming from and how you'd like to use it? The more details you can provide, the better the answers can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this value comes from a binding, then introduce a Converter class that takes in a numeric and returns a string.

Converter tutorial: http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

You can also format a binding without a converter using just StringFormat in the binding expression but that is more limited than a converter. see:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx  - Adding StringFormat to a binding
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx  - Format strings allowed

You can use String.Format("",...) in C# code to convert numerics to formatted strings.

For your example (assumes too much about length of number):

```
int x = 34549321;
string xs = string.Format("{0:#,##,k}",x);
// Produces xs = 34,549k
```

Comment: It appears that I just need a 'Custom Numeric Format Strings' code, it's not specific for Xaml. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: @Dork non-xaml example added

Comment: And how do I get rid of last 3 digits? I have a working application, I just need to change 'TextFormatting="###E+0">' into what I need.

Comment: @Dork Working example added to answer